# Pentaho Kettle Data Integration Parent Child Solution required

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a source table (from a MS DB) that contains a field "ParentID", which references the PK of "ID"

The target Postgres table is filled (new "ID" PK inserted from sequence) and the "ParentID" is set to null.
The stream has a the new PK inserted within it.

So now at this stage i have a valid stream of

```
"ID"  "ParentID"  "NewTargetID" 
100   NULL        1
101   100         2
```

How do I do a "Stream Lookup" (or maybe something else) and lookup the values to create a new stream field
to give me a new field of "NewParentID"

```
"ID"  "ParentID"  "NewTargetID"  "NewParentID"
100   NULL        1              NULL -< (How do i generate this ?)
101   100         2              1 -< (How do i generate this ?)
```

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2):

David,

As I'm a new member of StackOverflow I can't post images, so I posted a solution on my blog here:

http://funpdi.blogspot.com/2012/09/parent-child-lookup.html

I also put this link on your [Pentaho Forum post](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?128895-Paent-Child-problem-How-do-i-solve-it), my reply is waiting for approval by the moderator.

Comment: You should post the important parts of the answer here, and just post the URL to the image; someone with enough reputation will edit in the image (and the URL can be clicked on in the meantime). Without the important parts of the answer being posted on this site, the answer risks being deleted, or even being mistaken for spam (since you link to your own site)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, you can use the "Add sequence" step for this.  It would add a new field to the stream.

Here's the doc:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Add+sequence